# convert decimal numbers to ascii

Tags: python

What would be the right way to convert set of decimal numbers into ASCII representation in Python? I have a bunch of lines like that: `99104101101115101` and if I manually separate these numbers to `'99 104 101 101 115 101'` then it will give `'cheese'`. Source data set have no spaces, no separators.  **Assume that the data only contains characters in a-z A-Z 0-9**.

Comment: You'd have to split the numbers into valid ASCII ranges, however, how would you know that the `99 104` shouldn't be `9 9 10 4`, for example?

Comment: @cricket_007 if the OP specified that the characters were all A-Z a-z, this would be solvable, but that isn't specified.  I'm voting to close this question as "Unclear What you Are Asking" for that reason.

Comment: Let's consider a-zA-Z0-9 as a valid ranges. Any propositions of code?

Comment: @cricket_007 _"how would you know that the 99 104 shouldn't be 9 9 10 4, for example?"_  Because 4, 9, and 10 are not printable ascii.  Further, the OP has since limited the range of interest to `a-zA-Z0-9`.  (Granted that this is something the OP should have stated from the start.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('1?..', lambda m: chr(int(m.group())), '99104101101115101')
'cheese'
```

Demo with a random string of a million [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters):

```
>>> import random
>>> original = ''.join(chr(random.randrange(32, 127)) for _ in range(1000000))
>>> len(original), original[:50]
(1000000, 'Ty-@u8ZJnh=`/Z*s,\\+@T PgZ/CE"Nq\\wXvqvDn`&)~BmP$n;f')

>>> encoded = ''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in original)
>>> len(encoded), encoded[:50]
(2284738, '84121456411756907411010461964790421154492436484328')

>>> decoded = re.sub('1?..', lambda m: chr(int(m.group())), encoded)
>>> decoded == original
True
```

Comment: Good answer to a bad question. +1

Comment: Real clever, +1.  Could fail spectacularly if the data is bad, but who cares ..

Comment: Great answer Stefan, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The printable ascii range runs from 32 to 126.  Thus:

```
>>> s = '99104101101115101'
>>> s2 = re.sub('3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-6]', r' \g<0>', s)
>>> s2
' 99 104 101 101 115 101'
>>> ''.join(chr(int(x)) for x in s2.split())
'cheese'
```